# Show gif animation popup while processing in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

I have a method inside of one of my controllers that requires some seconds to process. I would like to have a gif animation popup while this occurs but I only get a static image. This is my code:

```
@FXML
public void search(ActionEvent e) {


    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    Group popup = new Group();
    Image image = new Image("file:resources/images/bender.gif");
    ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
    popup.getChildren().add(view);
    Scene dialogScene = new Scene(popup);
    dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
    dialog.show();

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Match msg = stablishSearchConditions();
            TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("ROOT");
            int indexName = 1;
            String mensaje = "Mensaje ";
            treeLabelResults.setText("");
            arbol.setRoot(root);

            for (Match message : msg.each()) {

                TreeItem<String> nodo = new TreeItem<String>(mensaje + indexName);
                root.getChildren().add(nodo);
                root.setExpanded(true);
                String mens = message.getMessage();
                TreeItem<String> nodo2 = new TreeItem<String>(mens);
                nodo.getChildren().add(nodo2);

                indexName++;
            }
            dialog.close();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blocking the fx application thread by running the expensive operation on this thread. This prevents your UI from updating, including animating the GIF.

Move the expensive operations to a non-application thread instead and only use `Platform.runLater()` to "commit" the ui updates:

```
Runnable expensiveTask = () -> {
    // expensive operations that should not run on the application thread
    Match msg = stablishSearchConditions();
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("ROOT");
    int indexName = 1;
    String mensaje = "Mensaje ";

    for (Match message : msg.each()) {
        TreeItem<String> nodo = new TreeItem<String>(mensaje + indexName);
        root.getChildren().add(nodo);
        root.setExpanded(true);
        String mens = message.getMessage();
        TreeItem<String> nodo2 = new TreeItem<String>(mens);
        nodo.getChildren().add(nodo2);

        indexName++;
    }

    // update ui -> application thread
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        treeLabelResults.setText("");
        arbol.setRoot(root);
        dialog.close();
    });
};

// start new thread for expensiveTask
new Thread(expensiveTask).start();
```